# Can javascript pass itself from inside the constructor

Tags: javascript, class, object

How can i go from this:

```
var abc = (function(){ 
  ..  
})();

register(abc); // outside the protected class
```

to this: (whithout calling register outside the class):

```
function register(object){ stores the object }

var abc = (function(){
     ..       

     register(this); // inside the protected class
})();
```

Some background.

A master-class has an object-array of plugins the 'register' function places the plugin. abc would be such a plugin. the plugins following the module patern closures. I would like to place the plugin instances into the list and the plugin be as selfcontained as possible. Additional functions outside the plugin i would like to remove.

I considered:
MasterClass.plugins.abc = (function..) 
but i think this creates a dependency on MasterClass.plugins to be instantiated before any plugins are loaded.

Comment: This looks awkward. To reduce the coupling between abc and register you should at least pass the register function to the constructor (think "injection").

Comment: The assignment doesn't occur until evaluation of the right hand side expression is complete, so anywhere inside the IIFE *abc* will be undefined.

Comment: Perhaps you can explain more about what you want?

Comment: i don't see whats the problem with the second method as long as you don't redefine register in your second function the register function would be available to you because of the closure, the major stepback is that you would be coupling your class to the register function, which is a bad idea, so like @Makkes said you should pass your register function as a constructor parameter so if at some point you decide to provide other registration method you just need to change the function that constructor is being called, and it will also be helpful for testing what makes it a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Function.prototype.bind() (to modify the **this** value) and a var inside, like this:

```
(function(){
var fun = function(){ alert( this.toString() )}
fun.bind(fun)();
})()
```

In your case:

```
(function(){
var fun = function(){ alert( this.toString() )}
register(fun);
})()
```